# Flex BorderContainer with dashed lines border

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to write a skin for BorderContainer with dashed line stroke. I haven't found a property in SolidColorStroke or *Stroke class that provides this feature. Is there a Stroke class that provides dashed lines drawing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not included with default fxg primitives but there are some third party libraries such as http://www.tink.ws/blog/primitives/